# Call function in service from broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have been struggling with the problem.
I have a Broadcast receiver that is suppose to receive SMS' and it does that, but I want to use a method/function in my Service, the intent is to make it a foreground service eventually, that never shuts down.
The Broadcastreceiver looks like this:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            }
        //want to send msgs[] to SmsService 
        }                         
    }
}
```

In the manifest for making it receive I have added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" > 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name= "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="SmsService"></service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, SmsService.class);
myIntent.putExtra("msg", msgs);
context.startService(myIntent);
```

Comment: I handle use it like this from service right? Hard to test for me since app crashes right after receive text so can see what goes wrong            Bundle bundle= service.getExtras();
      SmsMessage[] messages = (SmsMessage[])bundle.get("msg");
      handleReceivedSMS(messages);

Comment: yes. I believe your app crashes because you have your service listed as "SmsService" in manifest instead of ".SmsService".

Comment: tried with .SmsService, still creashes, but i can see have 1 main thread and 2 thread binders might be there i have made a mistakem anyway that is a different problem, I stepped though the code and it did fire the funktion i wanted, just the return part of startservice that breaks. Så thx for the help Robin